# Android style "curtain"

Tags: jquery, android, html, css

I'm trying to create a menu that works like the android notification drop-down area. (where you drag down from the top)

The menu has to contain it's own scrollbar, images and be animated (scroll down, not just jump)

How would i go about doing this, and is it even possible?

ps: this is not for mobile, so i don't want to have to drag it, just click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try looking at the slidingdrawer? You'll be able to figure out a way to open it on click as well.